# ASP vbscript email form - only send fields with value

Tags: forms, email, asp-classic, vbscript

This is the ASP code to send email..

```
<%
'declare variables
Dim EmailFrom
Dim EmailTo
Dim Subject
Dim DealerName
Dim DealerNumber
Dim InvoiceNumber
Dim PONumber
Dim InvoiceDate
Dim ModelNumber
Dim SerialNumber
Dim ConditionofUnit
Dim ReasonforRMA
Dim OtherText
Dim ModelNumber2
Dim SerialNumber2
Dim ConditionofUnit2
Dim ReasonforRMA2
Dim OtherText2
Dim ModelNumber3
Dim SerialNumber3
Dim ConditionofUnit3
Dim ReasonforRMA3
Dim OtherText3
Dim ModelNumber4
Dim SerialNumber4
Dim ConditionofUnit4
Dim ReasonforRMA4
Dim OtherText4
Dim ModelNumber5
Dim SerialNumber5
Dim ConditionofUnit5
Dim ReasonforRMA5
Dim OtherText5
Dim ModelNumber6
Dim SerialNumber6
Dim ConditionofUnit6
Dim ReasonforRMA6
Dim OtherText6
Dim ModelNumber7
Dim SerialNumber7
Dim ConditionofUnit7
Dim ReasonforRMA7
Dim OtherText7
Dim ModelNumber8
Dim SerialNumber8
Dim ConditionofUnit8
Dim ReasonforRMA8
Dim OtherText8
Dim ModelNumber9
Dim SerialNumber9
Dim ConditionofUnit9
Dim ReasonforRMA9
Dim OtherText9
Dim ModelNumber10
Dim SerialNumber10
Dim ConditionofUnit10
Dim ReasonforRMA10
Dim OtherText10

' get posted data into variables
EmailFrom = Trim(Request.Form("EmailFrom")) 
EmailTo = "ouremail@domain.com"
Subject = "my subject"
DealerName = Trim(Request.Form("DealerName")) 
DealerNumber = Trim(Request.Form("DealerNumber")) 
InvoiceNumber = Trim(Request.Form("InvoiceNumber")) 
PONumber = Trim(Request.Form("PONumber")) 
InvoiceDate = Trim(Request.Form("InvoiceDate")) 
ModelNumber = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber")) 
SerialNumber = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber")) 
ConditionofUnit = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit"))
ReasonforRMA = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA")) 
OtherText = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText")) 
ModelNumber2 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber2")) 
SerialNumber2 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber2")) 
ConditionofUnit2 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit2"))
ReasonforRMA2 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA2")) 
OtherText2 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText2")) 
ModelNumber3 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber3")) 
SerialNumber3 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber3")) 
ConditionofUnit3 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit3"))
ReasonforRMA3 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA3")) 
OtherText3 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText3")) 
ModelNumber4 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber4")) 
SerialNumber4 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber4")) 
ConditionofUnit4 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit4"))
ReasonforRMA4 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA4")) 
OtherText4 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText4")) 
ModelNumber5 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber5")) 
SerialNumber5 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber5")) 
ConditionofUnit5 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit5"))
ReasonforRMA5 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA5")) 
OtherText5 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText5")) 
ModelNumber6 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber6")) 
SerialNumber6 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber6")) 
ConditionofUnit6 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit6"))
ReasonforRMA6 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA6")) 
OtherText6 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText6")) 
ModelNumber7 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber7")) 
SerialNumber7 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber7")) 
ConditionofUnit7 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit7"))
ReasonforRMA7 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA7")) 
OtherText7 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText7")) 
ModelNumber8 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber8")) 
SerialNumber8 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber8")) 
ConditionofUnit8 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit8"))
ReasonforRMA8 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA8")) 
OtherText8 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText8")) 
ModelNumber9 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber9")) 
SerialNumber9 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber9")) 
ConditionofUnit9 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit9"))
ReasonforRMA9 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA9")) 
OtherText9 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText9")) 
ModelNumber10 = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber10")) 
SerialNumber10 = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber10")) 
ConditionofUnit10 = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit10"))
ReasonforRMA10 = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA10")) 
OtherText10 = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText10")) 

Dim mail
Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail") 
mail.To = EmailTo
mail.BodyFormat = 0
mail.MailFormat = 0
mail.From = EmailFrom
mail.Subject = Subject

mail.Body = "This is an email generated." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Name: </b>" & DealerName & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Number: </b>" & DealerNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Number: </b>" & InvoiceNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>PO Number: </b>" & PONumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Date: </b>" & InvoiceDate & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 1 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 2 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 3 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 4 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber4 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber4 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit4 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA4 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText4 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 5 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber5 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber5 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit5 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA5 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText5 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 6 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber6 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber6 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit6 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA6 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText6 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 7 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber7 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber7 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit7 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA7 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText7 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 8 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber8 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber8 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit8 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA8 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText8 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 9 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber9 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber9 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit9 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA9 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText9 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 10 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber10 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber10 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit10 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA10 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText10 & "<br>"
mail.Send 

' redirect to success page 
Response.Redirect("complete.html")
%>
```

So as you can see instead of sending all 10 items in every email, does anyone know how I can only send the items that actually get filled out with values? Only filling out 1 item is required with the ability to do up to 10..

EDIT: I changed it to this:

```
Dim mail
Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail") 
mail.To = EmailTo
mail.BodyFormat = 0
mail.MailFormat = 0
mail.From = EmailFrom
mail.Subject = Subject
If Request.Form("ModelNumber2") <> "" Then
mail.Body = "This is an email generated." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Name: </b>" & DealerName & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Number: </b>" & DealerNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Number: </b>" & InvoiceNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>PO Number: </b>" & PONumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Date: </b>" & InvoiceDate & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 1 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 2 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText2 & "<br>"

ElseIf Request.Form("ModelNumber2") <> "" And Request.Form("ModelNumber3") <> "" Then
mail.Body = "This is an email generated." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Name: </b>" & DealerName & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Number: </b>" & DealerNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Number: </b>" & InvoiceNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>PO Number: </b>" & PONumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Date: </b>" & InvoiceDate & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 1 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 2 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText2 & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 3 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA3 & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText3 & "<br>"
'ElseIf Request.Form("ModelNumber4") = "" Then

'ElseIf Request.Form("ModelNumber5") = "" Then

'ElseIf Request.Form("ModelNumber6") = "" Then

'ElseIf Request.Form("ModelNumber7") = "" Then

'ElseIf Request.Form("ModelNumber8") = "" Then

'ElseIf Request.Form("ModelNumber9") = "" Then

'ElseIf Request.Form("ModelNumber10") = "" Then
Else
mail.Body = "This is an email generated." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Name: </b>" & DealerName & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Number: </b>" & DealerNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Number: </b>" & InvoiceNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>PO Number: </b>" & PONumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Date: </b>" & InvoiceDate & "<br>" & _
"<b>------ ITEM 1 ------</b><br>" & _
"<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Serial Number: </b>" & SerialNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Condition of Unit </b>" & ConditionofUnit & "<br>" & _
"<b>Reason for RMA: </b>" & ReasonforRMA & "<br>" & _
"<b>Other Text <i>(If Applicable)</i></b>: " & OtherText & "<br>"
End If
mail.Send
```

But when I fill out 3 items it still only sends the email for 2 items. What am I missing here?

Comment: Lots of if statements. For example `if ModelNumber <> "" then mail.Body = mail.Body & "<b>Model Number: </b>" & ModelNumber & "<br>"`

Comment: Can you please look at the edit I made and help please!

Comment: Nevermind.. just have to add the opposite checks to each one too

Answer (score 0):

I would reduce the amount of typing with a loop...
(easiest if you add the "1" to the end of the first set of fields)
Been a while since I did any Classic ASP but from memory this should work:

```
mail.Body = "This is an email generated." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Name: </b>" & DealerName & "<br>" & _
"<b>Dealer Number: </b>" & DealerNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Number: </b>" & InvoiceNumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>PO Number: </b>" & PONumber & "<br>" & _
"<b>Invoice Date: </b>" & InvoiceDate & "<br>"

for i = 1 to 10
    if trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber" & cstr(i))) <> "" then
        mail.Body += "<b>------ ITEM " & cstr(i) & " ------</b><br>" & _
            "<b>Model Number: </b>" & trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber" & cstr(i)) & "<br>" & _
            "<b>Serial Number: </b>" & trim(Request.form("SerialNumber" & cstr(i))  & "<br>" & _
             ...
    end if
next
```